# Angular $http get request just adds received JSON to $scope variable instead of replacing it on every refresh

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, get, pull-to-refresh

I have this simple controller action that should do the whole magic of requesting some json objects and display them in a list:

```
$scope.onReload = function() {
  $http.get('http://some-demu-url.com/items.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  });
};
```

The concept is simple: the function is initialized when the app boots up (like this: $scope.onReload();) and that works very well.

However, I have a refresh action who fires the onRefresh function when the user pulls something down. **The new data should replace the old data** when the refresher is activated, but that's not what happens! The new data gets pulled but gets added to the list instead of replacing the old.

That means if the JSON contains Information for two list Items A & B:

- On init, there are A & B in the list (as intended)
- On the first refresh are still A & B from the init **plus** A & B from the new get request.
- The second time are already 6 items (A, B, A, B, A, B) in the list

and so on...!

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Code looks good. I would assume it is something else, not in this portion. Is something appending data to your json?

Comment: Please look at the response headers that get returned when the json response is served. I think the cache headers are being set and the browser is caching the results. Also, is this browser dependant or are you getting the same problem in all browsers?

Comment: @DhruvChandna I discovered in the Safari inspection tools (in the "resources"-section) that the pulled json files remain in cache so if I pull to refresh two times I have the json file 3 times in the XHRs folder (this folder is generated by the developer tools to structure the site's data). That means everything remains until I refresh the page by hand. I'm now trying to turn off the caching but I can't get it to work.. (Cache-Control is set to max-age=0 in the response header and doesn't seem to change...)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the complete solution but try initializing the items (in your OnReload()) to empty:

$scope.items = {};

As already mentioned, I would also look at potential caching issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried this also but it doesn't change anything if I test it...